# Determine the Taylor Series for $(1+x)^n$ about $x=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Having trouble solving this.
I get to expanding to this:
$$1^n + n(1^{n-1})\cdot\frac {x!}{1!}+n(n-1)\cdot 1^{n-2} \cdot \frac {x^2}{2!} +n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot 1^{n-3}\cdot \frac {x^3}{3!}\dots$$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Hint:$$1^{\textrm{anything}}=1$$

Comment: OK, then compact $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots (n-k+1)}{k!}$ to ${n\choose k}$

Comment: What you'll get as the Taylor series is:

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(\frac{n!}{i!\cdot (n-i)!}\cdot x^i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{n}{i}x^i$$

Comment: [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maclaurin+of+%281%2Bx%29^n)'s the W|A link that verifies it.

Comment: As you can see, we're back to the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$.

Comment: So the binomial theorem has to be used regardless of whether this series is finite or infinite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Taylor series" here has a finite number of terms, because the function in question is a polynomial. You can find the expansion in $x$ using the binomial theorem:
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} x^j.$$

I assume here that $n\ge 0$. For $n<0$, you can also use the binomial theorem, but the result is slightly different. You get an infinite series.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the series has an infinite number of terms.

Comment: @user2837598 If you really mean the function $(1+x)^n$ and not something else, then it certainly has a finite number of terms in its Taylor expansion.

Comment: @user2837598: the series has infinite number of terms if $n<0$.

Comment: @AlexR. I usually assume variables denoted by $n$ are natural numbers. Nonetheless, I've edited my answer to consider $n<0$.

Comment: Ah, so if n is a positive integer, k, then the coefficients of x^n for n>k are all 0? I'm starting to see where the above equation came from. Thank you all.

Comment: @user2837598 Yes, that is right.

Comment: @user2837598 Your approach of explicitly computing each Taylor coefficient will also work and give the same answer, but this is a little faster.